# Python: getting filename case as stored in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, case, filenames

Though Windows is case insensitive, it does preserve case in filenames.  In Python, is there any way to get a filename with case as it is stored on the file system?

E.g., in a Python program I have filename = "texas.txt", but want to know that it's actually stored "TEXAS.txt" on the file system, even if this is inconsequential for various file operations.

Comment: (accidental duplicate accounts merged)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the simplest way to do it:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> win32api.GetLongPathName(win32api.GetShortPathName('texas.txt')))
'TEXAS.txt'
```

Comment: Does `win32api.GetLongPathName(win32api.GetShortPathName('texas.txt'))` work?

Comment: Yes, that works. Actually, to clarify, your original suggestion does work, but not if including a directory - e.g., `win32api.GetLongPathName('\\states\\texas.txt')` yields `'\\states\\TEXAS.txt'`, whereas `win32api.GetLongPathName(win32api.GetShortPathName('\\states\\texas.txt'))` correctly yields `'\\STATES\\TEXAS.txt'`. That had confused me, now I'm all set. Thanks!

Comment: I see. Then, I have modified my answer to call `win32api.GetShortPathName` as well.

Comment: Great solution; to clarify: The puzzling inner `GetShortPathName()` call is needed, because `GetLongPathName()` does _not_ case-correct paths that are _already_ in long (non-8.3 format). In Python 3.x, the example works as-is even with non-ASCII filenames, but in 2.x you'll have to use Unicode strings explicitly and call `GetLongPathNameW()` (note the `W`) instead. If you have `pip`, you can install the `win32api` module (via the `pypiwin32` package) by running `pip install pypiwin32`

Comment: Note that this solution will *not* work if the file has no short filename (which can happen if short filename generation is disabled on the system or on the volume).  Additionally, `GetLongPathName` will not correct the capitalization of the drive letter.

Comment: This seems to fail in some cases, see https://github.com/thonny/thonny/issues/925

Answer (score 6):

I had problems with special characters with the win32api solution above. For unicode filenames you need to use:

```
win32api.GetLongPathNameW(win32api.GetShortPathName(path))
```

Comment: Good point (applies to Python 2.x - not needed on 3.x, which is natively Unicode). Just to be explicit: the input path (too) must be a Unicode string (e.g., `u'texas.txt'`).

Comment: See my comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2114975/179715 ; this isn't guaranteed to work if short filename generation is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

This one is standard library only and converts all path parts (except drive letter):

```
def casedpath(path):
    r = glob.glob(re.sub(r'([^:/\\])(?=[/\\]|$)|\[', r'[\g<0>]', path))
    return r and r[0] or path
```

And this one handles UNC paths in addition:

```
def casedpath_unc(path):
    unc, p = os.path.splitunc(path)
    r = glob.glob(unc + re.sub(r'([^:/\\])(?=[/\\]|$)|\[', r'[\g<0>]', p))
    return r and r[0] or path
```

**Note**: It is somewhat slower than the **file system dependent** Win API "GetShortPathName" method, but works platform & file system independent and also when short filename generation is switched off on Windows volumes (`fsutil.exe 8dot3name query C:`). The latter is [recommended](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633453%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) at least for performance critical file systems when no 16bit apps rely anymore on that:

```
fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 1
```

Comment: It's also necessary to protect square brackets in paths like `copy[12]`. I'm augmenting the answer using `glob.escape` if you don't mind

Comment: @robyschek yes, however I embedded the protection directly into the sub, so that it also supports ending `[` 's (as in `oddfilename[` , `oddfilename]`) and Py 2.7 & <3.4

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir("./")
['FiLeNaMe.txt']
```

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
import os
a = os.listdir('mydirpath')
b = [f.lower() for f in a]
try:
    i = b.index('texas.txt')
    print a[i]
except ValueError:
    print('File not found in this directory')
```

This of course assumes that your search string `'texas.txt'` is in lowercase. If it isn't you'll have to convert it to lowercase first.

Comment: `print ([f for f in os.listdir("mydirpath") if f.lower() == "texas.txt"]+["file not found"])[0]`

Comment: @Roger: Haha, great stuff! I'm still getting to grips with the power of list comprehensions. I tend not to post one-liners for answers though, since they can often be more confusing than illuminating :).

Comment: Just a note: No need to use string.lower() anymore.

Comment: The `except` block functionally does nothing -- thus ignoring errors silently.

Comment: @Chinmay: look closely at the statements in your `except` block (i.e, the last line of your program). It does **nothing**.

Answer (score 1):

and if you want to recurse directories

```
import os
path=os.path.join("c:\\","path")
for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if file.lower() == "texas.txt":
              print "Found: ",os.path.join( r , file )
```