# In Python, how can I get the correctly-cased path for a file?

Tags: python, windows, filenames

Windows uses case-insensitive file names, so I can open the same file with any of these:

```
r"c:\windows\system32\desktop.ini"
r"C:\WINdows\System32\DESKTOP.ini"
r"C:\WiNdOwS\SyStEm32\DeSkToP.iNi"
```

etc.  Given any of these paths, how can I find the true case?  I want them all to produce:

```
r"C:\Windows\System32\desktop.ini"
```

`os.path.normcase` doesn't do it, it simply lowercases everything. `os.path.abspath` returns an absolute path, but each of these is already absolute, and so it doesn't change any of them.  `os.path.realpath` is only used to resolve symbolic links, which Windows doesn't have, so it's the same as abspath on Windows.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Looks like this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113822/python-getting-filename-case-as-stored-in-windows, which has the answer.

Comment: "Windows uses case-insensitive file names" -- no, it doesn't. Windows preserves that case of filenames. Ie: The filenames themselves are defined with case, and that case is preserved if, for example, you copy the file. It is simply that certain operations in Windows ignore case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple, stdlib only, solution:

```
import glob
def get_actual_filename(name):
    name = "%s[%s]" % (name[:-1], name[-1])
    return glob.glob(name)[0]
```

Comment: I like this: it tricks `glob` into doing the `os.walk` for me!

Comment: It fix only file name, not previous subdirs. I add another answer, based on this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14742779/1355726

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  Also, it would fail for filenames with characters in them that are glob tokens.  If it did trigger a directory scan, it would probably be pathologically slow too...

Answer (score 13):

Ned's `GetLongPathName` answer doesn't quite work (at least not for me). You need to call `GetLongPathName` on the return value of `GetShortPathname`. Using pywin32 for brevity (a ctypes solution would look similar to Ned's):

```
>>> win32api.GetLongPathName(win32api.GetShortPathName('stopservices.vbs'))
'StopServices.vbs'
```

Comment: See my comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2114975/179715 ; this isn't guaranteed to work if short filename generation is disabled.

Comment: If you care about the full path, note that this will not convert a drive letter to the more typical upper-case.

Comment: Note: For this file system dependent solution check if short filename generation is switched off on Windows volumes (`fsutil.exe 8dot3name query C:`) - which is [recommended][1] at least for performance critical file systems when no 16bit apps rely anymore on that:

    (`fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 1`)


  [1]: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633453%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 11):

In Python 3 you can use the `pathlib`'s `resolve()`:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> str(Path(r"C:\WiNdOwS\SyStEm32\DeSkToP.iNi").resolve())
r'C:\Windows\System32\desktop.ini'
```

Comment: Note: sometimes you may get a completely different path in this case as it's resolving links (for instance, if you have a `subst` drive this may end up resolving it to where that `subst` points to).

Answer (score 9):

[Ethan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7133137/1355726)  correct only file name, not subfolders names on the path.
Here is my guess:

```
def get_actual_filename(name):
    dirs = name.split('\\')
    # disk letter
    test_name = [dirs[0].upper()]
    for d in dirs[1:]:
        test_name += ["%s[%s]" % (d[:-1], d[-1])]
    res = glob.glob('\\'.join(test_name))
    if not res:
        #File not found
        return None
    return res[0]
```

Answer (score 9):

This one unifies, shortens and fixes several approaches: 
Standard lib only; converts all path parts (except drive letter);  relative or absolute paths; drive letter'ed or not; tolarant:

```
def casedpath(path):
    r = glob.glob(re.sub(r'([^:/\\])(?=[/\\]|$)', r'[\1]', path))
    return r and r[0] or path
```

And this one handles UNC paths in addition:

```
def casedpath_unc(path):
    unc, p = os.path.splitunc(path)
    r = glob.glob(unc + re.sub(r'([^:/\\])(?=[/\\]|$)', r'[\1]', p))
    return r and r[0] or path
```

Comment: This one is the only one in this thread that worked for me. thanks!

Comment: It does not work if there is a `[` in the path. Must add `path.replace('[', '[[]')` before the `glob` statement...

Answer (score 7):

[This python-win32 thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-January/006642.html) has an answer that doesn't require third-party packages or walking the tree:

```
import ctypes

def getLongPathName(path):
    buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(260)
    GetLongPathName = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLongPathNameW
    rv = GetLongPathName(path, buf, 260)
    if rv == 0 or rv > 260:
        return path
    else:
        return buf.value
```

Comment: It may fail because `path` must be unicode for `GetLongPathNameW`. Try to replace `path` in the call `GetLongPathName(path, buf, 260)` with `unicode(path)`.

Comment: This doesn't work.  GetLongPathName only expands short filenames, so if you give it "C:\Progra~1" you'll get "C:\Program Files", but if you give it "C:\PROGRAM FILES", it's already a long pathname so it won't change it.

Answer (score 4):

Since the definition of "true case" on NTFS (or VFAT) filesystems is truly bizarre, it seems the best way would be to walk the path and match against [os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir).

Yes, this seems like a contrived solution but so are NTFS paths. I don't have a DOS machine to test this on.

Comment: This is the non-straightforward solution I was afraid of... :(

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the approach of Ethan and xvorsx. AFAIK, the following wouldn't also harm on other platforms:

```
import os.path
from glob import glob

def get_actual_filename(name):
    sep = os.path.sep
    parts = os.path.normpath(name).split(sep)
    dirs = parts[0:-1]
    filename = parts[-1]
    if dirs[0] == os.path.splitdrive(name)[0]:
        test_name = [dirs[0].upper()]
    else:
        test_name = [sep + dirs[0]]
    for d in dirs[1:]:
        test_name += ["%s[%s]" % (d[:-1], d[-1])]
    path = glob(sep.join(test_name))[0]
    res = glob(sep.join((path, filename)))
    if not res:
        #File not found
        return None
    return res[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Based off a couple of the listdir/walk examples above, but supports UNC paths

```
def get_actual_filename(path):
    orig_path = path
    path = os.path.normpath(path)

    # Build root to start searching from.  Different for unc paths.
    if path.startswith(r'\\'):
        path = path.lstrip(r'\\')
        path_split = path.split('\\')
        # listdir doesn't work on just the machine name
        if len(path_split) < 3:
            return orig_path
        test_path = r'\\{}\{}'.format(path_split[0], path_split[1])
        start = 2
    else:
        path_split = path.split('\\')
        test_path = path_split[0] + '\\'
        start = 1

    for i in range(start, len(path_split)):
        part = path_split[i]
        if os.path.isdir(test_path):
            for name in os.listdir(test_path):
                if name.lower() == part.lower():
                    part = name
                    break
            test_path = os.path.join(test_path, part)
        else:
            return orig_path
    return test_path
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `os.walk`, but I think that for diskw with many directories it may be time consuming:

```
fname = "g:\\miCHal\\ZzZ.tXt"
if not os.path.exists(fname):
    print('No such file')
else:
    d, f = os.path.split(fname)
    dl = d.lower()
    fl = f.lower()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('g:\\'):
        if root.lower() == dl:
            fn = [n for n in files if n.lower() == fl][0]
            print(os.path.join(root, fn))
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just struggling with the same problem. I'm not sure, but I think the previous answers do not cover all cases. My actual problem was that the drive letter casing was different than the one seen by the system. Here is my solution that also checks for the correct drive letter casing (using win32api):

```
  def get_case_sensitive_path(path):
      """
      Get case sensitive path based on not - case sensitive path.
      
      Returns:
         The real absolute path.
         
      Exceptions:
         ValueError if the path doesn't exist.
      
      Important note on Windows: when starting command line using
      letter cases different from the actual casing of the files / directories,
      the interpreter will use the invalid cases in path (e. g. os.getcwd()
      returns path that has cases different from actuals).
      When using tools that are case - sensitive, this will cause a problem.
      Below code is used to get path with exact the same casing as the
      actual. 
      See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113822/python-getting-filename-case-as-stored-in-windows
      """
      drive, path = os.path.splitdrive(os.path.abspath(path))
      path = path.lstrip(os.sep)
      path = path.rstrip(os.sep)
      folders = []
      
      # Make sure the drive number is also in the correct casing.
      drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
      drives = drives.split("\000")[:-1]
      # Get the list of the form C:, d:, E: etc.
      drives = [d.replace("\\", "") for d in drives]
      # Now get a lower case version for comparison.
      drives_l = [d.lower() for d in drives]
      # Find the index of matching item.
      idx = drives_l.index(drive.lower())
      # Get the drive letter with the correct casing.
      drive = drives[idx]

      # Divide path into components.
      while 1:
          path, folder = os.path.split(path)
          if folder != "":
              folders.append(folder)
          else:
              if path != "":
                  folders.append(path)
              break

      # Restore their original order.
      folders.reverse()

      if len(folders) > 0:
          retval = drive + os.sep

          for folder in folders:
              found = False
              for item in os.listdir(retval):
                  if item.lower() == folder.lower():
                      found = True
                      retval = os.path.join(retval, item)
                      break
              if not found:
                  raise ValueError("Path not found: '{0}'".format(retval))

      else:
          retval = drive + os.sep

      return retval
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an even simpler version that the "glob trick" so I made this, which only uses os.listdir().

```
def casedPath(path):
    path = os.path.normpath(path).lower()
    parts = path.split(os.sep)
    result = parts[0].upper()
    # check that root actually exists
    if not os.path.exists(result):
        return
    for part in parts[1:]:
        actual = next((item for item in os.listdir(result) if item.lower() == part), None)
        if actual is None:
            # path doesn't exist
            return
        result += os.sep + actual
    return result
```

edit: it works fine by the way. Not sure that returning `None` when path doesn't exist is expected, but I needed this behaviour. It could raise an error instead, I guess.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: mmm a kind of answer I guess :) I came up here to look for a simpler solution than mine, but actually mine turned out to be fine :D. I wonder if os.scandir would be more efficient, but I guess it depends on how fast the matching name is found.